# Wrong (future) convert to datetime

Tags: sql, date, datetime, type-conversion

These numeric values needs to be converted into date time. It is date of birth so the values can not be in the future. Can I somehow implement a rule that not accept date-of-birth where the value would equal to over 100 years old??

201246-1324
040210-6387
111257-0647
040210-6387

Result:

**2046-12-20 00:00:00.000 - Wrong**
2010-02-04 00:00:00.000 - Right
1957-12-11 00:00:00.000 - Right
2010-02-04 00:00:00.000 - Right

Comment: How do you know the first one is 2046, and not 1946?

Comment: The first is **NOT** 2046 - It is 1946. Hence I write WRONG. I know it because you can not have a date of birth in the future.

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked "why is your query returning 2046?"; can you show the query you're using?  it's obviously a two digit year cutoff issue.

Comment: select  convert (datetime,  Stuff(Stuff((substring([Cpr nr],1,6)),5,0,'.'),3,0,'.'), 4) as CprasDate
 FROM [samletlifeline2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporarily change your cutoff, since you're working with DOBs which are always in the past..

```
sp_configure 'two digit year cutoff', 2015
reconfigure
```

Then use a standard datediff on years < 100.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datediff function in an if statement for this circumstance i believe
Essentially, if the time between the two dates being compared is greater than 100 years then do not insert the record
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp

Comment: Yes I need the Datediff I need to combine     select  convert (datetime,  Stuff(Stuff((substring([Cpr nr],1,6)),5,0,'.'),3,0,'.'), 4) as CprasDate
 FROM [samletlifeline2]

Comment: with  DECLARE @dob  datetime
SET @dob='1987-06-19 00:00:00'

SELECT DATEDIFF(hour,@dob,GETDATE())/8766 AS AgeYearsIntTrunc

Comment: if ( datediff( year,getdate(), @dob) < 100 )
 insert into .....
 else
 dont insert into

Answer (score 0):

First, future dates using a 2-digit year can be prevented by adding the current century to the value and checking against the current year. If greater, subtract a century, otherwise take the value straight. So...

```
[YearCol] + round(year(getdate()),-2) -
  CASE
    WHEN [YearCol] + round(year(getdate()),-2) > year(getdate()) THEN 100
    ELSE 0
  END
```

As a side note, You might lobby the data source to provide a 4-digit format for year.

As for preventing insertion of centurians? Good luck. With your incoming data, you have absolutely no way to determine whether the birthdate is not in the contemporary century or no. No matter what you do, you have insufficient data in your incoming stream to make that call. If you have control over the source numbers you sampled, change the format.